# Require password to view webpage [jQuery, JavaScript, or PHP]

Tags: php, jquery, password-protection

I have a page that I would like to password protect. This page should be accessible if the user hits the URL [www.webpage.com/page.php](http://www.webpage.com/page.php) It will be emailed to the user along with a verification code.

I have most of the page written with jQuery. I would like to know how I can prevent access to the page without a proper password. After the user has entered proper password and has verified it will then display the content.

I tried doing something with jQuery dialog, and hiding the content then showing it after verification, however the user can view the content if they view the source of the page.

How should I go about doing so?

I'm just trying to avoid creating a new page. I guess I will have to use sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the validation that they are using (the right) password in PHP and *only* then actually output the content to them. If they don't have the password, tying to hide it from visibility is a no-win scenario.

Commonly, [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) variables are used for this. The verification script checks the user login/password and it it is accepted, assigns a session variable to the user.

Then in your actual code (for the secret page) you check against this session variable and if it is there, you go ahead and display the content to the user, if it isn't matched, you either display an error message or redirect the user off to another page through a `header()`.

Comment: so in this case, i would need to create a login site, where i have a and once they verify then save it to sessions, then if sessions is authenticated then give access? Is there any other way?

Comment: @Jareddlc There are lots of ways to protect user content (as there are lots of ways to do just about anything in coding) but this is probably the most straightforward, simple and reliable approach.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do this but if you protected the page by password  only client side its not a good even ok idea since the user can modify the JavaScript/jquery for that you can  load the content by ajax after verifying the password  .

to prevent the access without the password don't load the data it the password doesn't verifying (since i think you are verifying the password by ajax)

Comment: yes, im using jquery.post() method. I guess there no escaping having a pre-page that verifies user and have sessions

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a quick and easy solution, you can also consider using HTTP authentication with PHP. It can be as easy as the following

```
<?
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please input"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Please enter the correct username and password.';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Username: ".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."<br>";
    echo "Password: ".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']."<p>";
    $username = "demo";
    $password = "demo";
    if(($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)) {
        echo "Login Failed!";
    } else {
        echo "You're in!";
    }
}
?>
```

You can also find a more elaborate implementation [here](https://www.php.net/features.http-auth).